# Python loop over non-inherited attributes in base class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have a baseclass that contains nummerical attributes that are simply passed to it on initialization as a dictionary and then added to the instance's dictionary:

```
class baseclass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def calcValue(self):
        return sum(vars(self).values())
```

Now I have a derieved class from this class, that adds additional attributes to the class, e.g.;

```
class childclass(baseclass):
    def __init__(self, stringValue, **kwargs):
        super(childclass, self).__init__(kwargs)
        self.name = stringValue
```

Now I would like to have a function in my baseclass that only iterates over all attributes that were added to the class but not the one that were added as child attributes. For example if I create an instance of child class like this:

```
instance = childclass("myname", a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

and then call the calcValue method, it should return 1+2+3 = 6

```
instance.calcValue()
```

but since vars(self) will return the full dictionary, uncluding the string from the childclass attribute, which of course can then not be added. Is there a way to only acces the attributes of the instance that belong to the respective derieved class?

Comment: If I had a problem like this, I would contemplate whether the design is right. If you want to separate things, make the separation explicit, one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing all your attributes as ordinary values on the instance's `__dict__`. Which means that without any further hints, they are indistinguishable one from another.

Python has a couple mechanisms to treat attributes in special manners. If you would declare the attributes in your base class in the class itself, and just init their values inside the `__init__` method, it would be possible to introspect the base class' `__dict__` (and not the instance's `__dict__`), or the `__annotations__` attribute in the same class.

As it is in the example, though, one easy thing is to use an special attribute to take note of the attributes that are added on the base class, and you then consult this as the attributes' name source:

```
class baseclass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        self._numeric_attrs = set(kwargs.keys())

    def calcValue(self):
        return sum(getattr(self, attr) for attr in self._numeric_attrs)
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple, safe and effective - but with  added overhead - would be to store the base class attributes in a distinct attribute and use `__getattr__` to serve them:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._attribs = kwargs

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self._attribs[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError("object {} has no attribute {}".format(type(self).__name__, name))

    def calcValue(self):
        return sum(self._attribs.values())
```

I usually try to avoid `__getattr__` as it makes the code harder to inspect and maintain, but since your class has already no definite API it doesn't make much difference here.

Comment: Doing this would prevent the attributes from being changed, but for explictly modifying the `__attribs` dictionary. Keeping these attributes in a separate data-structure is obviously a solution, but some care have to be taken.

Comment: @jsbueno indeed.